# Filling premade unbound datagridview columns during runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView with unbound data, when I run the code below it creates new columns besides the already existing ones. What do I need to do to prevent that from happening?

```
    Dim connection2 As SqlConnection
    connection2 = New SqlConnection(clVariables.dbTestConnectionString)
    Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("DoGetSomething")
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)

    CMD.Connection = connection2
    CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 1

    Dim ds As Data.DataSet = New Data.DataSet
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    dbtTableTmp.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    dbtTableTmp.ReadOnly = True
    dbtTableTmp.Refresh()
```

Comment: Then you need to edit cells, yo do so with datagridview1(column,row).value=something

Comment: How can i tell datagrid to fill only from some data in dataset, do you know of some examples from which I can study?

Comment: Ah no, I misunderstood your question. Your issue is that your update creates new columns. I don't quite remember how to fix it, it can be fixed. But you will need to wait for someone more knowledgeable to hop in.

Comment: Set  [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns) to `False`. Set the predefined [Columns.DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname) to the name of the Columns in the DataTable you want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using...End Using blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

You can pass the connection directly to the constructor of the command along with the name of the stored procedure.

Since you are marking your grid an read only you have no need for a data adapter and since we are only dealing with one table, no need for a data set.

The second parameter of `.AddWithValue` is the value to be added to the database. You are mixing up `.Add` with `.AddWithValue`. The `.Add` method is preferred for several reasons. There is another problem here. The datatype can't be VarChar and the value 1. 1 is an Integer and VarChar is a string. I have guessed .Int but check the database to see what is correct.

Follow the directions the @Jimi provided in comments.

```
Private Sub FillGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using connection2 As New SqlConnection(clVariables.dbTestConnectionString)
        Using CMD As New SqlCommand("DoGetSomething", connection2)
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            CMD.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1
            connection2.Open()
            dt.Load(CMD.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    dbtTableTmp.DataSource = dt
    dbtTableTmp.ReadOnly = True
    dbtTableTmp.Refresh()
End Sub
```